# установка Git on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, git

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При установке Git получется такой результат. В чем проблема? Как исправить?

Comment: ? `apt update` `apt install`

Comment: ???? сначала sudo apt-get update, потом sudo apt-get install git?

Comment: ага, если не поможет - гуглить "обновить ключи репозиториев ubuntu". но это не точно ( :

Comment: дело в том, что и на апдейт тот же результат.... Может быть с системой что то?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139444

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan до этого что установили? и были ли ошибки или не полностью установленные пакеты? вообще сделайте `sudo apt-get -f install` для этого, потом `sudo apt-get upgrade`, после попробуйте с ново установить `git`.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, `upgrade`?? может `update`

Comment: откройте /etc/apt/sources.list в текстовом редакторе и посмотрите, что у вас там сконфигурировано по нескольку раз. удалите лишние записи. перед этим желательно сохраните копию.

Comment: @qwabra `update` это запуск обновления, а потом само обновление `upgrade`. а `update` как видно по комментариям он уже сделал.

Comment: @RazGalstyan, `update` у автора не прошел ©"Reading package lists... Error!"
 а `upgrade`, если мне не изменяет память, обновит версию системы, что может быть нежелательно

Comment: @qwabra ну значит по очереди `apt-get -f install`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Git не имеет никакого отношения к вашему вопросу. Лучше удалите все его упоминания, чтобы никто лишний раз не приходил сюда из гугла.

Comment: Все, отлично получилось, друзья! Перешел в ссылку, рекомендованную сверху, удалил, переустановил "пекедж"-ы, потом уже гит благополучно установился.... ++++++++++++

Comment: : ) теперь добавьте ответ к своему вопросу и отметьте его галочкой

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часто вижу такое на старых серверах Ubuntu

Если читать сообщение об ошибке внимательней - менеджер жалуется на не соответствие списков пакетов на машине и репозитории.

Решения, котрые гоняются ежедневно:

удалить списки, скачать заново и обновить систему:

```
~# rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
~# apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

Если не помогло, с офф-сайта скачать ISO и достать из него `/etc/apt/source.list`, обновить тот, что на системе в данный момент и повторить первый шаг.

Потом уже ставить нужные пакеты:

```
~# apt-get -y install git
```

Если замарочится времени нет, качайте *deb пакет из репы (смотрите в source.list текущую) и ставите вручную:

```
~# apt-get download git && dpkg -i git*deb
```